# Troubleshooting enums with efcore.pg

Tags: c#, enums, entity-framework-core, migration, npgsql

Are there any best practices in troubleshooting `enum`s when using with `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` provider? It's just that I don't know where to look anymore.
Here is how I register them:

```cs
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public SexType SexType { get; set; }
}

public enum SexType
{
    Male,
    Female,
}
```

```cs
public class MedServiceDbContext : DbContext
{
    public const string DatabaseSchema = "public";

    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; protected set; }

    static MedServiceDbContext()
    {
        NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<SexType>($"{DatabaseSchema}.{NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.DefaultNameTranslator.TranslateTypeName(nameof(SexType))}", NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.DefaultNameTranslator);

        //NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<SexType>();
    }

    private static void MapTypes(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .HasPostgresEnum<SexType>(DatabaseSchema, NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.DefaultNameTranslator.TranslateTypeName(nameof(SexType)), NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.DefaultNameTranslator);
        ;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        MapTypes(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) =>
        optionsBuilder
            .UseNpgsql(@"Host=localhost;Database=TestEnum;Username=postgres;Password=123")
            .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Trace)
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
        ;

    public MedServiceDbContext()
    {
    }
}
```

And this is how a migration looks like:

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AlterDatabase()
        .Annotation("Npgsql:Enum:public.sex_type", "male,female");

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Clients",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
                .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn),
            Name = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
            SexType = table.Column<SexType>(type: "public.sex_type", nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Clients", x => x.Id);
        });
}
```

And when used in a clean repro project it works flawlessly. It also works in a Test. But the same code (copy pasted) doesn't work in the main project giving me:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while reading a database value for property 'Client.SexType'. The expected type was 'MedService.API.Database.Entities.Enums.SexType' but the actual value was of type 'MedService.API.Database.Entities.Enums.SexType'.
 ---> System.InvalidCastException: Can't cast database type public.sex_type to Int32
   at Npgsql.Internal.TypeHandling.NpgsqlTypeHandler.ReadCustom[TAny](NpgsqlReadBuffer buf, Int32 len, Boolean async, FieldDescription fieldDescription)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 ordinal)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 ordinal)
   at lambda_method256(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at lambda_method256(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
```

I've checked every relevant piece of code but the only difference is how the database context is created. The main project uses DI the same way like a Test project whereas repro creates a context directly. So logically if main project and a Test project work the same they both should behave the same, but they are not.

I've checked every generated SQL scripts, LINQ expressions, etc. Everything seems to be same, but I keep getting this exception.

Where else should I look for issues?
I've confirmed that `sex_type` is created in both, main and repro projects. They are identical (checked using DBeaver). More than that the database structure is also completely identical. The database itself is created using `dotnet ef database update`.

P.S.
No, `ReloadTypes()` doesn't help here either. Checked that already.

Provider version used: `6.0.3`
PostgreSQL version used: `14.2`

**UPDATE_01**

Made some experiments and this works:

```cs
var connection = (Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection)_medServiceDbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
connection.Open();

using (var cmd = new Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand("SELECT c.\"Id\", c.\"Name\", c.\"SexType\" FROM public.\"Clients\" as c", connection))
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var id = reader.GetFieldValue<int>(0);
        var surname = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(1);
        var sex = reader.GetFieldValue<SexType>(2);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", id, surname, sex);
    }
}
```

Whereas this doesn't:

```cs
_medServiceDbContext.Clients.AsNoTracking().ToArray()
```

The latter gives the mentioned exception (`Can't cast database type public.sex_type to Int32`).
My guess is that for some reason EF provider uses [`GetInt32()`](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/ed59682462803653bbe205d5b94bf0c8ac1cc886/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlDataReader.cs#L1109) override of the `NpgsqlDataReader` implementation instead of [`GetFieldValue<T>()`](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/ed59682462803653bbe205d5b94bf0c8ac1cc886/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlDataReader.cs#L1594).

**UPDATE_02**

I've actually finally managed to assemble a [repro](https://github.com/uhfath/TestPostgreSqlEnum). It seems the issue is related to a usage of multiple different contexts targeting the same database connection. Described my findings [here](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/2324).

Comment: I copy-pasted your code pretty much as-is, and it works for me ([see this gist](https://gist.github.com/roji/cf6143ccf3461921d44fc773c56182eb)); this is with EF Core 6.0. Can you please provide a fully runnable (but minimal) sample - like my gist - which shows the error happening?

Comment: I've updated my initial post with a [link](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/2324) to the issue on github. I didn't think that my other contexts (used for auditing and identity) could interfere so never mentioned them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who will stumble into this, current workaround (until this [issue](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1026) is addressed) is to manually `MapEnum` all enums from all database contexts somewhere else, not inside of each `DbContext` static constructor as currently suggested in [docs.](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/enum.html?tabs=tabid-1#mapping-your-enum)
For example inside static constructor for a `Startup` class of the app. Or something like that.